# BigQuery Api getQueryResults returning pageToken for 0 records

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

We have a query which returns 0 records sometimes when called. When you call the getQueryResults on the jobId it returns with a valid pageToken with 0 rows. This is a bit unexpected since technically there is no data. Whats worst is if you keep supplying the pageToken for subsequent data-pulls it keeps giving zero rows with valid tokens at each page.
If the query does return data initially with a pageToken and you keep using the pageToken for subsequent data pulls it returns pageToken as None after the last page giving a termination condition.

The behavior here seems inconsistent?Is this a bug?

Here is a sample jobresponse I see:
Here is a sample job response:
{u'kind': u'bigquery#getQueryResultsResponse', u'jobReference': {u'projectId': u'xxx', u'jobId': u'job_aUAK1qlMkOhqPYxwj6p_HbIVhqY'}, u'cacheHit': True, u'jobComplete': True, u'**totalRows**': u'**0**', u'pageToken': **u'CIDBB777777QOGQFBAABBAAE**', u'etag': u'"vUqnlBof5LNyOIdb3TAcUeUweLc/6JrAdpn-kvulQHoSb7ImNUZ-NFM"', u'schema': {......}}

I am using python and running queries on GAE using the BQ api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue that has lingered for far far too long. It is fixed in this week's release, which should go live this afternoon or tomorrow.